# Is Chinese Checkers a solved game

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, board-games, research

Is there a machine or algorithm available to solve the board game "Chinese checkers"? If there is please let me know about relevant material. I have already searched over internet unfortunately i am unable to have relevant details about it.

Comment: You may be interested in this https://www.quora.com/Is-two-player-chinese-checkers-a-solved-game

Comment: I have already reviewed that question and asked the author of the answer about the references but he/she did not reply to my query. Plus the link author has provided does not have the relevant information i am looking for.

Comment: Please tell us what research you've already done, what you've found, and why it doesn't meet your needs.  This helps others from duplicating the effort that you've already done, helps get you better answers, makes the question more valuable for others, and demonstrates that you have put in some time and the answer isn't readily available.

Comment: I have searched on google scholar already so i may find some relevant material to answer my question that I have asked above. Unfortunately I am unable to find any relevant research paper that answers this question.Plus I have searched for any other material that answers this question but no clue. On the other hand i have read  it on wikipedia that it is solved for 2 players. But I am unable to have reference for that claim. I want to research on this game and I am trying to find out the end point of the current research from which i can start my efforts.